# Difference between slicing of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, `mat` is a NumPy array and I create different views from the array using slicing operation, with different rows as `row1, row2, row3`.

Then I try to modify each row, but why am I not able to modify the actual array `mat` in case of `row3`?

```
mat = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
row1 = mat[0, :] #[1 2 3 4] 
row2 = mat[1:2, :] #[[5 6 7 8]]
row3 = mat[[2], :] #[[ 9 10 11 12]]
row1[0] = -1 #[-1  2  3  4] 
row2[0,0] = -5 #[[-5  6  7  8]] 
row3[0,0] = -9 # [[-9 10 11 12]]
print(mat)
```

The output in this case is

```
[[-1  2  3  4]
 [-5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]]
```

Why is `row3` not referencing to the original array?

Comment: So what you are really asking is why `mat[0, :]` and `row1[0]` modify the original array but `mat[[0], :]` and `row1[0, 0]` do not. Right?

Comment: `mat[[2], :]=-9` will work.  That's because the assignment is part of the indexing, not a separate step as with `row3`.  `mat.__setitem__(([2],slice(None), -9)`.  `row3` uses a `__getitem__()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html#indexing-operations) operation you are doing on `row3` is considered [advanced_indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), numpy will always create copies during advanced indexing and views during normal indexing